# Need to get a list of all scheduled reports/dashboards that belong to my organization, each with its running user

Tags: reporting, dashboard, scheduled, runas

As we have a massive number of scheduled reports in our organization this information will be very useful in maintaining the report schedule. Some users are inactive and some reports are failing due to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of scheduled jobs with: `SELECT Id, CronJobDetailId, CronJobDetail.Name, State, CreatedBy.Name, OwnerId FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.JobType = '8' AND State != 'DELETED'` with `CronJobDetail.Name` being the report id.

Additional querying is required to filter where the running user is inactive and to get the actual name of the report.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_cronjobdetail.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm

Answer (score -2):

List of reports can be obtained by running SOQL: `SELECT CreatedDate,Description,DeveloperName,Id FROM Report`

same thing with dashboard

To find list of all scheduled reports, easiest way is to find them is in scheduled jobs

Comment: Thanks @sf_user for the prompt reply, but this is not what I am looking for. This SOQL query only provides the "DeveloperName" which is not really a user.

Comment: Try adding createdby.Name to the query